# how can I get the selected value of dynamically created spinner android java

Tags: java, android, spinner

In my android application I have dynamically created spinners and i want to get selected value of dynamically created spinner and I am doing like below:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_answermultitext);

String Title = "";
        for (int count = 0; count < DropDown.length; count++) {
            Title = DropDown[count].split(":")[0];
            String DValue = DropDown[count].split(":")[1];
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                if (DValue.contains(arr[i])) {
                    DValue = DValue.replace(arr[i], "");
                }
                if(Title.contains(arr[i]))
                {
                    Title = Title.replace(arr[i], "");
                }
            }
            String[] data = DValue.split(",");

            ///Creating Text View
            tv[count] = new TextView(this);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    (int) LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    (int) LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.leftMargin = 25;
            params.topMargin = (count + 1) * (75 + add);
            tv[count].setText(Title);
            tv[count].setTextSize((float) 20);
            tv[count].setPadding(5, 15, 5, 15);
            tv[count].setLayoutParams(params);
            layout.addView(tv[count]);

            ///Creating Spinner
            Sp[count] = new Spinner(this);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    (int) LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    (int) LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            param.leftMargin = 25;
            param.topMargin = (count + 1) * (100 + add1);
            Sp[count].setPadding(5, 23, 5, 5);
            Sp[count].setLayoutParams(param);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, data);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            Sp[count].setAdapter(adapter);
            Sp[count].setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // Get select item

                        int sid = Sp[count].getSelectedItemPosition();
                        // spinnerDropDown.getSelectedItem().toString();
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                                "You have selected : " + DropDown[sid],
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                // drop_SelectedVal
                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }
            });
            layout.addView(Sp[count]);
        }
}
```

But I am getting below error in `onItemSelected()` method at this line `int sid = Sp[count].getSelectedItemPosition();`

```
Cannot refer to a non-final variable count inside an inner class defined in a different method
```

And when I add `final` with the `count` vaiable the above error is remove and I am getting below error at this line `for(int count = 0; count < DropDown.length; count++)`

```
The final local variable count cannot be assigned. It must be blank and not using a compound assignment
```

kindly suggest me how can I resolve it.

waiting for reply.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all about the error : the error is because you are accessing non-final Spinner object Sp[count] in inner class. So changing count to final will create another error but the previous problem is still not solved. Its just suppressed for time being when you will solve the error with count it will come again.

How to solve ?

**First** remove the final you added with the count.

**Second** if you want only the position of the selected item in the spinner you should do the following

```
  @Override
  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
   int selectedItem = position;
  }
```

**Third** If you want to get the String selected you should do the following :

```
@Override
  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
   String s = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
   // here's the change
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, its working fine but I have a problem that when Its run first time it gets spinner selected value and when I change selected value of spinner, `String s` have both value current and previous value, I want to use previous value I want to use only current value, how can i resolve it, suggest me.

Comment: I am not getting what u trying to say. String s will have only current value which is selected not the previous. If you are getting the previous value it might be a one time problem, try restarting the app. If still u are getting both values provide me some output what u are getting.

Comment: Also i have made a small change in the answer. Make sure you update your code

Comment: I have multiple dynamic dropdown then I am using this `String s += (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);` and when I update value of anyone of the dropdown the selected value add into the previous string and I want that each time it start from the empty string and add dropdown's value.

Comment: @user88 you are doing the same mistake you did in EditText. You have to declare String s=null outside the for loop. And if you want only currently selected value of the Spinner you should use = instead of +=

Comment: but I have one `onItemSelected` method for each dynamically created spinner

Comment: If you have onItemSelected for each Spinner then also just declare the String s=null first in the  onItemSelectedethod then in next line write.                s=(String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);     you will have the currently selected value in the string.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the

```
int position
```

on onItemSelected.

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
int position, long id) {
       int hereIsYourSelectedItem = position;
 }
```